# Getting error while converting Json data to Object in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsmutablearray, nsmutablestring

I am using an API to convert Json Data into Object data, 
please visit the API I am using 
[Please Visit the API page which I am using](http://yoga.lifehealthinfo.com/api/yoga_list/categories)

Here is the snap of my code with highlighted issues 
[Issues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89jsP.png)

and here is the raw code

```
 -(void) retrieveData{
    NSURL * url = [NSURLURLWithString:getDataUrl];
```

> ```
> NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
> jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options: kNilOptions error:nil];
>
> NSLog(@"JsonArray %@", jsonArray);
>
> //setup yougaArray
> yougaArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
>
> //Loop through our jsonArray
>
> for (int i = 0; i<jsonArray.count; i++)
> {
>     NSString * yId = [[[[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"data"]objectAtIndex:@"categories"]objectForKey:@"id"];
>    // NSString * yId = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"id"];
>     NSString * yName = [[[[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"data"]objectAtIndex:@"categories"]objectForKey:@"name"];
>     NSString * yDescription = [[[[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"data"]objectAtIndex:@"categories"]objectForKey:@"description"];
>     NSString * yImage = [[[[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"data"]objectAtIndex:@"categories"]objectForKey:@"image"];
>
>     //Add the city object to our citiesArray
>
>     [yougaArray addObject:[[Youga alloc]initWithYougaId:yId andYougaName:yName andYougaDescpription:yDescription andYougaImage:yImage]];
>
>      }
> [self.tableView reloadData];
>
>      }
> ```

Comment: `objectAtIndex:@"categories"` => Why putting a NSString there? Also, you need to understand the structure of the JSON before even trying to parse it.

Comment: can you print `NSLog(@"JsonArray %@", jsonArray);` ]

Comment: can you pass the integer value in the [arrayname objectAtIndex:0] like this access the array

Comment: Can you find a tutorial that isn't half a decade old?  There's no reason not to be using `[]` indexing.

Comment: so what should I do now? I've gone through the API, and there I used objectAtIndex:@"something"    where is" [ " used. and using ObjectForKey:@"something"    where "{ "  used.

Comment: yes @"Anbur.Karthik" jsonArray being printed pretty well... but when I am used to fetch my required data from that jsonArray it giving some error... if you needs then I can also add simulator's result

Comment: @FaizFareed: It's because you didn't understand the structure of your JSON, you don't parse it correctly. Nothing to do with the simulator. It's a Dictionary at top level, not an array!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @Lame, I followed your code, as it was giving me 6 to 8 errors, but I understand your code & configured error in that now here is the complete solution which works according to my requirements or (perfect answer according to my asked question)

```
-(void) retrieveData{
    NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:getDataUrl];
    NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    NSDictionary *dataJSON = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"data"];
    NSArray *allCategoriesJSON = [dataJSON objectForKey:@"categories"];

    yougaArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < allCategoriesJSON.count; i ++)
    {
        NSDictionary *aCategoryJSON = [allCategoriesJSON objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *yId = [aCategoryJSON objectForKey:@"id"];
        NSString *yName = [aCategoryJSON objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSString *yDescription = [aCategoryJSON objectForKey:@"description"];
        NSString *yImage = [aCategoryJSON objectForKey:@"image"];
        [yougaArray addObject:[[Youga alloc] initWithYougaId:yId andYougaName:yName andYougaDescpription:yDescription andYougaImage:yImage]];
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your JSON response its a `Dictionary` type object not an `array` so your code should be like this,

```
    NSMutableDictionary *dictData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options: kNilOptions error:nil];

    NSLog(@"JsonArray %@", dictData);

       NSArray *jsonArray=[[dictData objectForKey:@"data"] objectForKey:@"categories"];
    //setup yougaArray
    yougaArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


    for (int i = 0; i<jsonArray.count; i++)
    {


        NSString * yId = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"id"];
        // NSString * yId = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"id"];
        NSString * yName = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSString * yDescription = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"description"];
        NSString * yImage = [[jsonArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"image"];

        //Add the city object to our citiesArray

        [yougaArray addObject:[[Youga alloc]initWithYougaId:yId andYougaName:yName andYougaDescpription:yDescription andYougaImage:yImage]];

    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
```

Hope it works for you. Let me know!!
Happy coding. :)

Comment: Thanks for the contribution @Ravi, I've uploaded solution for the asked question please review that.

Answer (score 1):

You JSON seems like this :

```
{
"meta": {
    "status": "200",
    "msg": "OK"
},
"data": {
    "total_pages": 0,
    "total_categories": 2,
    "current_page": 1,
    "next_page": 0,
    "categories": [{
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Articles",
        "description": "Yoga Articles",
        "image": "http:\/\/yoga.lifehealthinfo.com\/uploads\/images\/50_50\/86289272image86289272.jpg"
    }, {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Poses",
        "description": "Yoga Poses",
        "image": "http:\/\/yoga.lifehealthinfo.com\/uploads\/images\/50_50\/86289272image86289272.jpg"
    }]
}
}
```

now replace your existing code with the code below:

```
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options: kNilOptions error:nil];

NSLog(@"JsonArray %@", jsonArray);

//setup yougaArray
yougaArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//Loop through our jsonArray

NSArray *dataArray = [[jsonArray objectForKey@"data"] objectForKey:@"categories"];

for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.count; i++) {
    NSString * yId = [[dataArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"id"];
    NSString * yName = [[dataArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"name"];
    NSString * yDescription = [[dataArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"description"];
    NSString * yImage = [[dataArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"image"];

    //Add the city object to our citiesArray

    [yougaArray addObject:[[Youga alloc]initWithYougaId:yId andYougaName:yName andYougaDescpription:yDescription andYougaImage:yImage]];
}

[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Let me know if the solution works for you, also if anything comes up.

Comment: Thanks @Siddharth Sunil for your time, Attention & Contribution, I've uploaded solution for the asked question. which is given by another person "Lame" with some errors which I resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This is the JSON:

```
{
    "meta": {
        "status": "200",
        "msg": "OK"
    },
    "data": {
        "total_pages": 0,
        "total_categories": 2,
        "current_page": 1,
        "next_page": 0,
        "categories": [{
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Articles",
            "description": "Yoga Articles",
            "image": "http:\/\/yoga.lifehealthinfo.com\/uploads\/images\/50_50\/86289272image86289272.jpg"
        }, {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Poses",
            "description": "Yoga Poses",
            "image": "http:\/\/yoga.lifehealthinfo.com\/uploads\/images\/50_50\/86289272image86289272.jpg"
        }]
    }
}
```

Your JSON is a `NSDictionary` at top level! Not a `NSArray`!
Also, avoid doing all `objectForKey:`/`objectAtIndex:` in the same line/instruction, it's harder to read, but also harder to debug, especially when you don't know what you are doing.
Also, when there is an error parameter, use it, don't put `nil`.

So:

```
NSError *errorJSON = nil;
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&errorJSON];
if (errorJSON)
{
    NSLog(@"ErrorJSON: %@", errorJSON);
    return;
}
NSDictionary *dataJSON = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"data"];
NSArray *allCategoriesJSON = [dataJSON objectForKey:@"categories"];
for (NSUIInteger i = 0; i < allCategoriesJSON.count; i ++)
{
    NSDictionary *aCategoryJSON = [allCategoriesJSON objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString yID = [aCategoryJSON objectForKey:@"id"];
    NSString yName = [aCategoryJSON objectForKey:@"name"];
    NSString yDescription = [aCategoryJSON objectForKey:@"description"];
    NSString yImage = [aCategoryJSON objectForKey:@"image"];
    [yougaArray addObject:[[Youga alloc] initWithYougaId:yId andYougaName:yName andYougaDescpription:yDescription andYougaImage:yImage]];
}
```

Comment: @Lame Thanks for the Help, First I followed above code by "Monika Patel" that was helpful but not giving me proper solution to load data into my required Objects I make minor suitable changes which could not given me my required solution as I was willing to put data into my created objects like as yId, yName, yDescription, yImage,  
But when I used your code it was giving few errors which I configured & now it is giving me my required solution. Wait I am submitting solution to its Answer area, 
Hence according me your suggested code is the right Solution.

Comment: I didn't challenge my code with a compiler. I just wrote it here. There may be small issue of syntax. What were the errors?

Comment: I've uploaded corrected version of your code, Please check that,  Thanks alot, your work is really really helpful.